# IronRuby Stack Trace

Tags: error-handling, stack-trace, ironruby, callstack

Greetings! We're working on an IronRuby project. There's a C# WPF application. We wrote a module for that application. When an error is raised in IronRuby, the application shows a message box. It only shows the error message. It does not show which Ruby script raised the error.

How do we get IronRuby to display the ruby file that raises the error?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this, you need to wrap your code with *begin rescue* like this:

```
begin
  # Write your ruby code here, that can have an error
rescue SyntaxError, NameError => boom
  str = "String doesn't compile:\n " + boom
  puts str
  puts boom.backtrace.join("\n")
rescue StandardError => bang
  str = "Error running script: " + bang
  puts str
  puts bang.backtrace.join("\n")
rescue
  puts "Unknown error happened"
end # rescues
```

Seem that Ruby interpreter throws an exception when error occurs, so you need to catch it and write its stack trace into messagebox. If you find another way, please write it here